# How to send page title as parameter in shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

How to get page title in to shortcode parameter's value?
I have custom php script written which accepts parameters, 
I can send hard coded shotcodes in parameter as value but I have to send the page's title in parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send post title in shortcode :

```
[myshortcode title='Web pages']
```

//  shortcode

```
function shortcode_myshortcode($atts) {

$atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'title' => 'no foo',            
        ), $atts);

return  $atts['title'];

}
add_shortcode('myshortcode', 'shortcode_myshortcode');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I understand your question, but to get the title of the current post use `get_the_title()`. You can use it within the shortcode function or when prepering the call for the custom php script you made.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/